# Eclipse - Number of times compiled over project?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, information-retrieval

My team just finished a huge project. We're going to present it to class in a week, and want to add some interesting stats.

Is there any way to find out how many times we've compiled the code over the last X days?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of but if you go into Project>Properties>Refactoring History you can see a detail of all the refactoring you've done. That may make for some interesting stats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such functionality but you can install a metrics plugin such as [this](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/) for other code metrics. Eclipse auto-compiles code so I'm not sure how useful such as statistic is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get the number of times you compiled. But if you want some similar (and hopefully useful) statistics, go to  `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history`. You will see the change history there. Each time you make a change, Eclipse keeps track of the change by creating a file here. Sort the files by date, and you can easily get some statistics to display for your presentation.